# Vue Router dynamic segment with params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to create a route that can handle both dynamic segments and accept router-props (params). Something like this:

`{ path: '/peer:body?', name: 'peer', component: () => import('pages/peer.vue'), props: true }`

And eventually push a route like this:

`this.$router.push({ path: '/peer/' + row.body, name: 'peer', params: { row: row } })`

Unluckily, I am only able to use dynamic segments using `path`as route property or params using `name`as route property, but never simultaneously.

Comment: Your route definition seems strange. What URL do your expect it to match exactly? Also when using object syntax, `params` can be used only with `name` and not with `path` (Vue router docs seems broken right now so I'm unable to post a link...)

Comment: @MichalLevý something like `http://localhost:8080/peer/body-of-message`. The intention is to have both dynamic segments and params working together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as you already mentioned, when constructing "location descriptor object" for `$router.push` (or `to` prop of `<router-link>`), you can use `path` or `name`, not both at the same time (doesn't make sense to do so)

Second, you can pass `params` only when you use `name` (as described [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) - paragraph between first two code samples). To overcome this you can use `query` instead of `params` or build whole `path` including the params into the URL string.

And that brings me to the most important part of my answer. It seems as you are trying to pass a complex object as a route param (and into the target component props). While this is technically possible, it's not a good way of doing things. You have no place in your path definition where to put content of such parameter - it will work with `push` or clicking `<router-link>` where parameter is provided as an object, but when user accesses that URL directly (by copying and pasting URL for example), the page will be broken because prop parameter will be missing (as it cannot be extracted directly from the URL).

So my advise is to avoid that. Put your data into something like Vuex and instead of passing whole object by router, pass only some kind of identifier that can be included in the URL, extracted by Router and passed as a prop into target component. Then your target component should grab the `Id`  and use it to query Vuex to get the data it needs...